# Why is a ClassCastException only thrown when the return value is accessed?

Tags: java, classcastexception

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268533/why-is-this-generic-method-unsafe)

Given this function:

```
public static <S extends CharSequence> S foo(S s) {
  return (S) new StringBuilder(s);
}
```

Why does this invocation execute without exception:

```
foo("hello");
```

But this one throws ClassCastException?

```
System.out.println(foo("hello"));
```

Comment: Did your compiler not give you a warning??

Comment: It warned in the method, but not on either invocation - was curious about why one invocation worked and the other threw the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics in Java 5/6 are [type-erased](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means that any generic type is fundamentally just an `Object` type (or whatever the least common denominator type is, which is in this case `CharSequence`) at runtime. The appropriate casts are inserted wherever needed. So your method gets type-erased to something that looks like this:

```
public static CharSequence foo(CharSequence s) {
  return (CharSequence) new StringBuilder(s);
}
```

And your call gets type-erased to this:

```
System.out.println((String)foo("hello"));
```

Apparently Java won't bother inserting the `(String)` cast if the return value is never used—why bother?

Answer (score 3):

Generic types are only available to the compiler, and are erasured (basically omitted) at runtime.  So the cast is ignored within the method