# Why doesn't @SneakyThrows throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, exception, generics, polymorphism, throws

This question just asks why the generic cast is not used. The questions about Erasure do not seem to explain this edge case.

Before I start let me preface this by saying **I am NOT interested in type inference as described here**:

[A peculiar feature of exception type inference in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316581/a-peculiar-feature-of-exception-type-inference-in-java-8/31316879#31316879)

This is just to avoid confusion.

**What I am interested in is why the following code works without throwing a** `ClassCastException` ?

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class GenericThrows {
    static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
        throw (T) d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest.<RuntimeException>test(new SQLException());
    }
}
```

Compile the code with:

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 GenericThrows.java
```

And it produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException
        at GenericTest.main(GenericTest.java:9)
```

My mental model of Java Generics and Type Erasure (and why I think this makes no sense):

**When the static method compiles:**

```
static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
        throw (T) d;
    }
```

Type Erasure wipes out all generic types and replaces them with the upper bound of given type, so the method effectively becomes:

```
static void test(Exception d) throws Exception {
        throw (Exception) d;
    }
```

I hope I am correct.

**When the main method is compiled:**

```
static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
        throw (T) d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest.<RuntimeException>test(new SQLException());
    }
```

The type parameter is replaced by the concrete type : `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

So the method effectively becomes:

```
static void test(Exception d) throws RuntimeException {
        throw (RuntimeException) d;
    }
```

I hope I am correct.

So, **when I try to cast a `SQLException` to a `RuntimeException` I should get a `ClassCastException`, this is exactly what happens if I write the code without generics:**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class NonGenericThrows {
    static void test(Exception d) throws RuntimeException {
        throw (RuntimeException) d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonGenericThrows.test(new SQLException());
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 NonGenericThrows.java
java NonGenericThrows
```

Results:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.sql.SQLException cannot be cast to class java.lang.RuntimeException (java.sql.SQLException is in module java.sql of loader 'platform'; java.lang.RuntimeException is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at NonGenericThrows.test(NonGenericThrows.java:5)
        at NonGenericThrows.main(NonGenericThrows.java:9)
```

**Then why does the generic version not give a ClassCastException ?**

**Where am I going wrong in my mental model ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) What you are looking for is called type erasure and it is not really specific to exceptions but applies generally to all generics (and casting to generic types)

Comment: Your mental model about generics is mostly correct. And if I remember correctly, you will get the `ClassCastException` when oyu try to access the thrown `Exception` as RuntimeException`. This all revolvesa around the cast. I cannot find the exact JLS paragraph, but it says something along the line of "type checks are intersted when necessary". This leads to situations where they are only insterted when the value is accessed, and at unexepected places.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268623/why-is-a-classcastexception-only-thrown-when-the-return-value-is-accessed) is related.

Comment: @dan1st I simply have no idea why people are linking older questions when they do not provide a clear understanding of THIS PARTICULAR CASE. No it doesn't answer my question, my question is simply why there is no ClassCastException thrown where it should be.

Comment: Very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77121729/lombok-sneakythrows-why-isnt-a-classcastexception-not-thrown)

Comment: @DuncG That was my question, I made a new question and deleted that one because it was causing confusion. People thought I was talking about type-inference.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes the question you linked seems to be related, however my question is passing in a concrete type and trying to cast to a generic type. Why is that cast not happening ? I pass in `SQLException` with a reference to its superclass `Exception`, it tries to cast it to `RuntimeException`, that should throw an exception, why does that not happen?

Comment: @Turing85 So is my cast ignored by the compiler ? But my code does not compile without the cast, so what gives. Is there no simple answer why this works ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. I'd need to analyze the bytecode. It looks like the cast would only take effect when we enforce that the thrown `Exceptoin` is - in deed - a `RuntimeException` (without another cast). A `catch (RuntimeException e) { ... }` does not catch the exception.

Comment: @Turing85 The confusing part is that it does not compile without the cast. So where how exactly is the cast being used ? A `catch(RuntimeException)` will obviously not catch it but it does not generate a ClassCastException also.

Comment: @Turing85 There is some info here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/08/4-out-of-5-java-developers-failed-to-solve-this-question.html

Comment: @Turing85 A `catch(RuntimeException e)` doesn't obviously work, as no RuntimeException is thrown. A `catch(SQLException e)` won't compile because of the Generic Type parameter the compiler expects a RuntimeException and not a SQLException.

Comment: @Turing85 If you could post your bytecode analysis that would be great.

Comment: @Turing85 Nope all that I told you above is nonsense. Just replace the cast with RuntimeException and you get a ClassCastException. Don't have the cast, the compiler complains about checked exceptions not being catched.

Comment: @Turing85 So, **the cast is used but also not used.** That's a WTF moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Type Erasure

You are correct that type variables are erased to their leftmost bound. This is stated in [§4.6 Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of the *Java Language Specification* (JLS).

> - The erasure of a type variable ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

That means that the erasure of:

```java
static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
    throw (T) d;
}
```

Is:

```
static void test(Exception d) throws Exception {
    throw (Exception) d;
}
```

But note this only relies on the **type parameter**. The *type argument* is irrelevant. Unlike languages such as C++, where each unique parameterization of a template results in unique compiled code, Java only compiles generics *once*. So, if you call the above with:

```java
ClassName.<RuntimeException>test(new SQLException());
```

You don't end up with byte code where `T`'s bound was changed to `RuntimeException`. The leftmost bound is still `Exception`.

### Byte-code

Generics do not *completely* disappear after compilation. If they did, then generics would be unusable when compiling against pre-compiled libraries.

With the `test` method above, it's true that the method itself cannot know what it was parameterized with. However, the fact that the method *is* generic with the type parameter `T extends Exception`, and that it `throws T`, is preserved. In other words, static generic information is recorded in the byte-code. You can even get this information via reflection.

Basically, generics are an "illusion" of the compiler. They are a *language* feature, not a *run-time* (JVM) feature. From the point of view of the compiler, generics always exist (unless raw types are involved).

This is why you do not need to handle the exception when calling `test` with `RuntimeException` (or some subclass) as the type argument. The *compiler* knows about `T`, and thus "knows" in this case that the method does not throw a *checked* exception. Yet notice the `(T) d` line of the `test` method gives an "unchecked cast" compiler warning. This warning occurs precisely because the cast may succeed, but that doesn't mean the code is not broken (e.g., claiming `T` is an *unchecked* exception, but then having the method actually throw a *checked* exception).

---

## Casting

From [§5.5 Casting Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) of the JLS:

> If a casting context makes use of a narrowing reference conversion that is checked or partially unchecked ([§5.1.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.2), [§5.1.6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.3)), then a run time check will be performed on the class of the expression's value, possibly causing a `ClassCastException`. **Otherwise, no run time check is performed.** *[emphasis added]*

And from [§5.1.6.2 Checked and Unchecked Narrowing Reference Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.2):

> - A narrowing reference conversion from a type `S` to a type variable `T` is unchecked.

And from [§5.1.6.3 Narrowing Reference Conversions at Run Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.3):

> - An unchecked narrowing reference conversion from `S` to a non-intersection type `T` is completely unchecked if `|S| <: |T|`.
>
>   Otherwise, it is partially unchecked.

Taking all that into account, the following:

```java
static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
    throw (T) d;
}
```

Is a *completely unchecked* cast. Thus, there is no check a run-time. You can verify this by looking at the byte code.

Comment: I love this answer. You hit the nail right on the head when you said that Java Generics compile only once. That's a misconception I had.

Comment: but there is one last thing bothering me: the `throws T` if the code is compiled to `throws Exception` then why does using `<RuntimeException>test()` give no compiler error ?

Comment: it should give me an error that I am still throwing an Exception without a catch, right ? Sorry for the stupid question, I am not familiar with the mathematical language of the JLS.

Comment: I rewrote my comments into a section of my answer. Does it still help answer your additional questions?

Comment: Another thing that might help: Java is a statically typed language. This allows the compiler to perform many verifications at compile-time. But sometimes the developer knows more than the compiler. Casts are basically the developer telling the compiler, "Trust me, I know what I'm doing". And generics are effectively just a way of giving the compiler more information to work with, thus letting the compiler implicitly perform many of these nearly-guaranteed-to-be-safe casts _for you_ ("unchecked" casts can still lead to `ClassCastException`s).

Comment: yes, if you can add these in the answer it will greatly help. I am not sure how reliable the comment system is.

Answer (score 2):

Your misconception is here:

> **When the main method is compiled:**
>
> ```
> static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
>     throw (T) d;
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     GenericTest.<RuntimeException>test(new SQLException());
> }
> ```
>
> The type parameter is replaced by the concrete type : `java.lang.RuntimeException.`
>
> ***So the method effectively becomes:*** << this is your misconception: the method doesn't change!
>
> ```
> static void test(Exception d) throws RuntimeException {
>     throw (RuntimeException) d;
> }
> ```

This is not how generics in Java work - the `test()` method is not recompiled nor otherwise changed in any way. The method is:

```
static <T extends Exception> void test(Exception d) throws T {
    throw (T) d;
}
```

Since `T` could by any `Exception`, the cast `(T) d` is effectively a no-op and the compiler doesn't produce any code for this cast (it **cannot** do a cast: the caller doesn't pass in the type `T` and the code **must** work for all `T extends Exception`, but `d` is necessarily an `Exception` anyway because this is the declared type of the parameter.)

The compiler only checks the call site. Is the passed parameter (`SQLException`) an `Exception` or any subclass of `Exception`? Yes, `SQLException` is a subclass of `Exception` and therefore the call compiles.

Comment: But the code fails, if I remove the cast `(T) d` and do not use `RuntimeException` as the parameter. That's what is confusing me.

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing generics with templates (à la C++). You were on the right track with mentioning type erasure which, as the name suggests, erases any trace of type information for compilation.

Thus, your cast doesn't really happen, or if it does it's not with the type you'd expect.

You'd need to use `Class#cast` to get the desired behavior, but getting an instance of `Class<T>` ain't convenient for your use case.

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to. This has nothing to do with Class<T> or Class#cast.

Comment: You don't have generics' type info at runtime, so the cast is effectively ignored, hence why you don't get the exception. Hence why you'd need to use `Class#cast`

Comment: All generic info is replaced with their bounds. Generic info is removed but the cast is not. So why is the cast not applied ?

Comment: Effectively it tries to should try to cast to RuntimeException. I cast should be there but I am concerned about why it is not applied.

Comment: @Vivick do you have some hard fact that the cast is "ignored"? I doubt that statement. There are cases where casts must not be ignored, no matter if generics are involved or not.

Comment: Ignored or to a type that isn't the expected one. As I understand it, casts with generics are applied to the "closest" bound. With no constraints, it should be `Object` (useless as everything is an `Object`). With a constraint, it should be to that constraint (redundant as we know the constraint is valid).